# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I keep getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' when I run this code. I'm unable to pinpoint the issue.

**When I do .head() this is what I get:**

```
|Year|Chinese|Malay|Indian|Others|
|----+-------+-----+------+------|
|2010|     96| 87.9|    92|  87.7|
|2011|   96.3| 89.3|  92.5|  91.7|
|2012|   97.1|   91|  92.5|  92.6|
|2013|   97.2| 91.7|  92.3|  93.6|
|2014|   97.5| 93.5|  93.2|  93.5|
```

**My code:**

```
df_tertiary = pd.read_csv('percentage-of-p1-cohort-that-progressed-to-post-secondary-education.csv',index_col=0);

df_tertiary_chi = df_tertiary[df_tertiary.race == 'Chinese']
df_tertiary_malay = df_tertiary[df_tertiary.race == 'Malay']
df_tertiary_indian = df_tertiary[df_tertiary.race == 'Indian']
df_tertiary_others = df_tertiary[df_tertiary.race == 'Others']

df_tertiary_total = pd.concat([df_tertiary_chi['percentage_p1_cohort_post_sec'],df_tertiary_malay['percentage_p1_cohort_post_sec'],df_tertiary_indian['percentage_p1_cohort_post_sec'],df_tertiary_others['percentage_p1_cohort_post_sec']], axis=1, sort=False)
df_tertiary_total.columns = ['Chinese','Malay','Indian','Others']
df_tertiary_total = df_tertiary_total.loc['2010':'2019']
df_tertiary_total = pd.DataFrame(df_tertiary_total)

display(df_tertiary_total.head())

plt.plot(df_tertiary_total)
plt.show()
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-200-1000efab126d> in <module>
     14 display(df_tertiary_total.head())
     15 
---> 16 plt.plot(df_tertiary_total)
     17 plt.show()
```

**Data Sample**

```
    Chinese Malay   Indian  Others
year                
2016    97.8    93.1    93.8    93.9
```

Comment: Please provide a data sample for which this error occurs (in **text** form) and state in which line it occurs.

Comment: Maybe you want `df_tertiary_total.plot()`

Comment: @cs95 It still doesn't work. However, I got a different error. ```TypeError: no numeric data to plot```

Comment: what kind of plot do you want?

Comment: @cs95 I'm trying to get a multiple line graph

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but `df_tertiary_total.set_index('Year').plot.line()` should plot multiple lines with Year as the x-axis.

Comment: @cs95 until you realize that his `.head()` has all `year` values at 2010! That will be some line graph.

Comment: @skuzzy it'll be some line graph only if they actually call `.head()` without plotting!

Comment: @skuzzy oh mai .-. I meant the date to be incrementing. I made a typo when creating the question.